# Counting, arranging 8 ppl

Tags: combinatorics

I should be able to solve this Problem in my sleep but i cant figure out why my solution is not right - i even have thought about the possibility that the textbook solution is wrong but I guess that would be pretty arrogant.

So here is the Question.

In how many ways can 8 people be seated in a row if there are 4 men and 4 women and no 2 men or 2 women should sit next to each other.

My solution and thoughts are as follows:

There are 4! ways to arrange the women and 4! ways to arrange the men, and the row can start with either a men oder a women so times two

4!*4!*2=1152
But the textbook solution shows 
5! *4!=2880 and I have no idea how they come up with that and what is wrong with my solution.

I would be very grateful for every hint that could help me understand.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you at first sight. It is a proven fact that books are sometimes wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped by this solution as well, and I think your logic is absolutely correct and the same way I would view it. We would consider the men and the women as 'blocks': there are 2 ways to arrange the 'blocks,' and 4! ways to arrange the members of the both of the two blocks, hence $2 \cdot 4! \cdot 4!$. I cannot figure out where they would get the additional factor of 5. My best guess is that your textbook is incorrect.

Comment: Here's a wild guess:  the author got the same answer as you, then misread the "2" as a "5", and folded the "5" in with a "4!" to give "5!".

Comment: Here's another way to get your solution: In the first place there can be any one of the 8, so we have 8 options. in the second place there can be one of 4 of the opposite sex and so on... so we get $8\cdot4\cdot3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1$

Comment: You can verify your logic with a simple case of 4 people (2 men and 2 women) and just count all possible valid arrangements out of the total 16 (which is $2\cdot2!\cdot2!=8$ and not $3!\cdot2!$).

Comment: The answer in the textbook is the number of ways that four men and four women can be seated in a row if no two men sit next to each other.

Comment: Thanks im so glad it really made me believe i did not understand the concepts of counting, it is a relive to know that at least in this case that i do understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook answer is incorrect.

Given condition is that no two men can sit next to each other, and the possible way to be seated that way is

```
                            M_M_M_M_
```

These $4$ men can be seated in $4!=24$ ways

Now, the remaining empty seats can be filled by women in $4!=24$ ways.

This can be done in $2$ ways.

Therefore, the number of ways to arrange $8$ people in a row if there are $4$ men and $4$ women and no $2$ men or $2$ women can sit next to each other is $2\times4!\times4!=2\times24\times24=1152$ ways

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Petra You're welcome :)